# Number of totally ordered subsets of a set.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have set with n elements. How many different totally ordered subsets (tosets) does this set have? I know that this is the same as the sum from $k=0$ to $n$ of the permutations on k elements. However I believe this can be closed to a product. Is this correct? Thank you very much.

Regards.

Comment: [This](http://oeis.org/A003422) answers your second question, but I believe you also need to select which subset of size $k$ you are totally ordering.

Comment: @vadim123 but that's just $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k!$ right? I want $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean a set with $n$ elements.  It sounds like you are not given an order, but allowed to choose the order, from you use of permutations on $k$ elements.  If so, you first have to select the $k$ elements from $n$, then permute them to make the order.

Comment: I think you need a factorial on the denominator, but then will be correct.

Comment: This is [OEIS 000522](http://oeis.org/A000522) which doesn't give a closed form.  How did I find that?  I calculated a few terms in Excel and searched for 13700,109601.  It remarks that it is very close to $en!$, a result due to Ramanujan.  If you take $en!$ and round down you have the answer.  If you think about the Taylor series for $e^1$ it is easy to see why.

Comment: excelent, could you add a link of that to the answer and copy this text or something please? I am going to use your answer for a different question. Thanks a lot btw.

Comment: The blue OEIS 000522 is a clickable link

Comment: No, I meant Ramanujan's result and the fact it is the floor of that.

Comment: It is referenced in the notes on OEIS as an asymptotic formula.  I just checked my numbers in Excel.

Comment: @Ross Millikan What do mean by closed form?

Comment: @mac07:  a "closed form" is not well defined.  It clearly excludes having a summation in the expression like in Jorge Fernández Hidalgo's comment to the question or a recurrence like the $a_n=na_{n-1}+1$.  I would accept $\lfloor en!\rfloor$, but I had missed that when I wrote that comment.